# Mac: Batch Scale Images same Aspect Ratio

Tags: mac, images, batch

I'm developing an iPhone application on a Mac, and have many, many images which I need to scale down.

These images are of varying size, however, what I know is they must all be resized to `110x130`, while maintaining the same aspect ratio.

I've tried every single Mac batch-image-scaler out there, and they all come with great options; however, they all return blurry images.

Using Preview to resize, my thumbnails are crisp and clear; the only issue is, there is no option to scale to a certain size while maintaining the aspect ratio. You can only specify one variable, either the height, or the width, not both. Again, I need my images to be precisely `110x130`.

So to recapitulate, does anyone know of a program on a Mac which could let me batch resize images to a particular size, *while* keeping the same height to width ratio ?

Comment: ResizeMe, ThumbsUp, iResize, Automator, and Preview (which I still have some hope will work).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use ImageMagick (it can be installed with `brew install imagemagick`):

`for f in *.png; do convert "$f" -filter lanczos2 -resize 110x130\> -extent 110x130 -gravity center "${f%.png}-small.png"; done`

`-resize 110x130\>` makes images smaller so that they are at least 110x130, and `-extent` crops them. `110x130^` would also make images larger. The default [filter for -resize](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) is lanczos (3-lobe lanczos), but the 2-lobe lanczos makes images slightly less sharp.

This converts images to jpg and saves them to a different folder:

`mogrify *.png -resize 110x130\> -extent 110x130 -gravity center  -format jpg -quality 92 -path ~/Desktop/thumbnails`

Answer (score 1):

After trying around ten programs, I stumbled upon ResizeIt, in the Mac App Store, which seems to do the trick perfectly.

Comment: thanks!! this silly task seems to be enormoussly difficult on a mac.. i just lost an hour trying to get Automator to do this. and not only does it seem to have horrible shotcomings as far as configuration goes i couldnt even get it to work.. because the scale task was not finding the images. and all the utilities google turned up were terrible as well.